# Кнопка в ячейке таблице при нажатии на которую внизу открывается доп. информация

Tags: angular2, typescript

В общем в разметке генерю элементы tr через *ngFor, а на кнопку вешаю вот такой обработчик:

```
  onDescriptionClick(assembly: Assembly) {
    let tableRow = $(`tr[id=${assembly.id}]`);
    tableRow.toggleClass('clicked');
    $('tr[id=\'description\']').remove();
    if (tableRow.hasClass('clicked')) {
      tableRow.after(`<tr id='description'><td colspan='4'>${assembly.description}</td></tr>`);
    }
  }
```

Который, относительно текущего tr снизу создает tr с доп. инфой.

Подскажите является ли это решение "чистым" или можно сделать красивее без прямого взаимодействия с DOM?

Comment: _можно сделать красивее без прямого взаимодействия с DOM_

Comment: @Grundy оформите пример ответом. Я правильно понимаю, что прямое воздействие на элементы не приветствуется в Ангулар?

Comment: у ангуляра есть свои инструменты для работы с DOM, но обычно хватает уже готовых директив. Например тут в ngFor вполне можно поместить template в котором будет два tr, у второго поставить ngIf, и показывать его в зависимости от значения свойства и практически весь метод `onDescriptionClick` уходит, и возможно заменится одной строкой `assembly.opened = !assembly.opened`

Comment: Попробовал сделать вот так: поместил 2 tr в ng-container, а у строки, которую нежно или не нужно отображать задал:, <ng-template *ngIf="_visibleDict.getValue(assembly.id)==true">, а между тегами саму tr, а по нажатию по кнопке onDescriptionClick  меняю значение, что-то не отображается.

Comment: по комментарию непонятно что ты сделал

Comment: @Grundy , вроде, разобрался и написал итоговый результат в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделал вот так:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let assembly of assemblies">
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{assembly.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{assembly.type.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{assembly.owner.login}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-toolbar mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" (click)="onDownloadClick(assembly)">Скачать</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1">Подробнее</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-1" (click)="onDescriptionClick(assembly)">Описание</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id='description' *ngIf="_visibleDict.getValue(assembly.id)==true">
      <td colspan='4'>{{assembly.description}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Событие на клик:

```
  onDescriptionClick(assembly: Assembly) {
    if (this._visibleDict.containsKey(assembly.id)) {
      this._visibleDict.setValue(assembly.id, !this._visibleDict.getValue(assembly.id));
    }
    else {
      this._visibleDict.setValue(assembly.id, true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: что такое `_visibleDict`?

Comment: @Grundy словарь ключ-значение из typescript-collection

Comment: @Grundy, не хотел просто модель менять, добавляя доп. поле и завел словарик.