# Применение стилей к динамически создаваемым элемента в Angular

Tags: css, angular2

В общем, создаю динамически элемент через JQuery и хочу, что бы к нему применялся стиль.

Далее обнаруживаю, что стиль не применяется из-за того, что Angular при компиляции добавляет какие-то атрибуты к селекторам стилей.

Как быть?

[Генерю дополнительную строчку при нажатии на кнопку.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961335/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
onDescriptionClick(assembly: Assembly) {
    let tableRow = $(`tr[id=${assembly.id}]`);
    tableRow.toggleClass('clicked');
    $('tr[id=\'description\']').remove();
    if (tableRow.hasClass('clicked')) {
      tableRow.after(`<tr id='description'><td colspan='4'>${assembly.description}</td></tr>`);
    }
  }
```

Стиль описан так:

```
#description {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

а после компиляции в стилях это:

```
#description[_ngcontent-c2] {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbInNyYy9hcHAvY29tcG9uZW50cy9hc3NlbWJseS1saXN0L2Fzc2VtYmx5LWxpc3QuY29tcG9uZW50LmNzcyJdLCJuYW1lcyI6W10sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiQUFBQTtJQUNJLGlDQUFpQztBQUNyQyIsImZpbGUiOiJzcmMvYXBwL2NvbXBvbmVudHMvYXNzZW1ibHktbGlzdC9hc3NlbWJseS1saXN0LmNvbXBvbmVudC5jc3MiLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyIjZGVzY3JpcHRpb24ge1xyXG4gICAgYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjogI2ZmZiAhaW1wb3J0YW50O1xyXG59Il19 */
```

**UPD:**
Если поставить ViewEncapsulation.None, то вылетает такая серия предупреждений и проект не запускается.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core.js 10:24-31
>   Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which
>   dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/selector.js 10:24-31
>   Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which
>   dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_tags.js
>   10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in
>   which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/tags.js
>   10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in
>   which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: по ссылке в вопросе.

Comment: Зачем дублировать вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961335/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @DaemonHK так вопрос разные. Первый вопрос- это про правильность подхода, а второй про решение проблем с CSS из-за этого похода.

Comment: @iluxa1810 может лучше тогда проблемный код сюда перенести?

Comment: о каких стилях идет речь? почему ты думаешь что он не применяется? Как он описан?

Comment: [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: @Grundy а дополнительно ничего не нужно делать? А то у меня предупреждения появляются при компиляции и в конечном итоге ничего не запускается.

Comment: Можно прочитать предупреждение и последовать предложенному совету :)

Comment: @Grundy , я дополнил вопрос. Может сможете помочь=)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773035/10123947

Comment: предупреждение лучше текстом тоже добавить

Comment: @Grundy вроде, норм. Оформите ответом. Еще дополните, чем чревато использование ViewEncapsulation.None. Как я понимаю, стили просто смогут перекрывать друг-друга между компонентами?

Comment: @iluxa1810, _ViewEncapsulation.None_ как ни странно, это отсутствие инкапсуляции, следовательно стили работают так, как обычно

Comment: @Grundy, не, я к тому, чем чревато отсутствие инкапсуляции. Ангуляр же не зря ее делает для себя.

Comment: @iluxa1810. _Ангуляр же не зря ее делает для себя_ - это спорный вопрос, есть мнение, что это делается для тех, кто не смог освоить cascading в css

Comment: @Grundy, в общем, потестил и стиль действительно стал глобальным и смог  задеть элементы другого компонента.

Comment: @iluxa1810, напиши ответ тогда, я помню были еще подобные вопросы, но не смог с ходу найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, если в `@Component` задать у encapsulation значение [ViewEncapsulation.None](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) импортировав из `import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';`, то стили будут создаваться без ангулярсих модификаций, которые изменили селекторы=> сгенерированный элемент попадет под селектор, однако, в таком случае стиль становится глобальным и может приминиться на другие компоненты.